# How do I prevent my Google Apps email being suspended for abuse, when sending bulk emails via Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

Background:
I have a Google Apps account for my domain; one email address from there was added as an Admin to my App Engine project.

App Engine happily sent email 'from' this email address for a few weeks. At some point, the email address was marked as 'suspended for abuse'. (Frustratingly, neither App Engine or Google Apps notified me about this.)

In doing my research, I found only a few comments about similar things happening to people on the old community pages. Eg: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6181

While it seems that some people have been able to unblock a Google Apps account by either (a) logging in and solving a CAPTCHA or (b) unlocking it via the Google Apps admin page, neither of these options are available to me.

I could set up a new email address and send email from there, but I'm concerned that this email would get blocked as well.

Does anyone have insights into this issue? Is there a TOS rule that I could be inadvertently breaking? Is there a know solution to this?

Comment: You could consider setting a real mailing list with http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman or http://www.sympa.org/ or something else, or perhaps a googlegroups group.

Comment: Unfortunately, every one of the emails is different. Each email is a 'system alert' that users will receive once or twice per day. (Or they can turn them off altogether if preferred.) Google App Engine has a facility to send email (at a cost of $0.01 per 100 emails) - so it seems _very_ odd that you wouldn't be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of [App Engine 1.6.3](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/02/app-engine-163-released.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+GoogleAppEngineBlog+%28Google+App+Engine+Blog%29&utm_content=Google+Reader)

> When an email is sent either from a user of a Google Apps domain from a request originating on that domain, or from an app administrator with an account on a Google Apps domain, a DKIM signature will be automatically applied to the email.

This change should improve email deliverability.

[Authenticating Mail: DKIM](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html#DKIM)

Answer (score 1):

App Engine applies similar rules to Gmail's for *outgoing* mail. Basically if App Engine decides your mail is spammy (based on rules that, for obvious reasons, can't be fully transparent) and if there's a lot of it, it may decide to suspend the account used to send the mail.

This page: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69585 has some info about how to make it less likely that your app's mail will be marked as spam.

Note that DKIM signing won't help here. If the mail never makes it out of App Engine, DKIM won't make a difference; it's used by recipients to decide if the mail is spam or not.

As mentioned on the groups page, we're planning to add notification of mail bounces, but don't have a definite timeline for that yet.